# Is there a way to hide a file from a public repository, but still have it be there?

Tags: python, github, heroku

I'm using GitHub and Heroku to host a Discord Bot, I dont want my files with bot tokens to be shown on the Git Repository but I still want them to be able to run on Heroku as usual. Any ideas?

Comment: You could have those tokens as environmental variables on your local computer (and the Heroku server), or store them in a file and add it to .gitignore (but downside here is that Heroku server wouldn't have key if its repository is a clone of upstream).

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do that. [Put it into an environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers your problem `https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/84enr3/how_to_host_a_discord_bot_on_heroku_for_free/`

Answer (score 0):

It's no a good idea to store any sensitive information on a Git Repository (Github, gitlab, bitbucket,...) even if it's private. Because your co-workers could see your passwords information. It's better to use Variables.

You have to use Encrypted Secrets here you can see the doc: [Creating and storing encrypted secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets)

And then on automatic build create a version of the bot with the secrets and upload it to the Heroku server (or to the serving directory).